# System.ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2015

I have the 6.2 entityframe work and the version of the .net framework is 4.5.1 and the version of the sql.data is 6.8.8 and i have this error

i can't have the revors engenerring done

```
System.ArgumentException: The specified store provider 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' cannot be found in the configuration, or 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' is not valid. ---> System.ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.
   at System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(String providerInvariantName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityStoreSchemaGenerator.CreateStoreSchemaConnection(String providerInvariantName, String connectionString, Version targetEntityFrameworkVersion)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityStoreSchemaGenerator.CreateStoreSchemaConnection(String providerInvariantName, String connectionString, Version targetEntityFrameworkVersion)
   at System.Data.Entity.Design.SsdlGenerator.EntityStoreSchemaGeneratorDatabaseSchemaLoader.CreateStoreSchemaConnection(String providerInvariantName, String connectionString, Version& storeSchemaModelVersion)
   at System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityStoreSchemaGenerator..ctor(String providerInvariantName, String connectionString, String namespaceName)
   at Microsoft.DbContextPackage.Handlers.ReverseEngineerCodeFirstHandler.ReverseEngineerCodeFirst(Project project)
```

Comment: Is your web.config file configured correctly?
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html

Comment: i don't know what to change in it ! i have an SQL database on wampserver and this is the file @pmcilreavy